# How to cover the android edge screen [Expokit]

Tags: android, react-native

I detached my react native app to **Expokit** recently, and found out there is a screen issue on Samsung Note 8. My app is not fully occupy the screen, there are two black space on the left and right. Do i need to configure my android project to make it fit to screen?

I've tried add android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode (shortEdges) to styles.xml. But no hope, the screen is fine before i detached my app.

Not only the app content is being resized, but also the splash screen. My root view component doesn't add any padding/margin style.

**Solution**
Finally i found the root cause, i added `<item><bitmap android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:src="@drawable/splash" /></item>` to splash_background.xml. `android:gravity="fill_vertical"` causing my app resized

`<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try out this in styles.xml

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen"> true </item>`

or you can try with flex :1

Comment: Will try the android:windowFullscreen tomorrow. By the way the i'm using the flex : 1 on my root view.

Answer (score 0):

Seems app is taking margin or padding from some root component. You need to see that.

Comment: Don't think so, the black bar is covered from the status bar to the bottom navigation bar, not only the app body.

Comment: Possibly because one screen is overlayed over another screen.

Comment: Try giving background color 'transparent' and see what happpens. Def color is white

Comment: Also if you've exported from expo then there may be a property defined on app.json which is `primaryColor` . Please refer to this link : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/

Comment: I set my app.js view background=red, but still no hope. My android device is 1440*2960 xxhdpi, is it possible the resolution causing this?

Comment: Don't think primaryColor is still working as my project is detached from Expo.

Comment: Don't think so. It depends on your styling. I still do feel there is some default margin or padding which is causing the issue. Please recheck the styles. Try rendering a single screen and then see it styles. Try seeing the style of `app.js`

Comment: If you have exported the project using expo kit, it saves the configuration from the `app.json` file. If you have not added that property it takes default value of white

Comment: Definitely not the margin/padding issue, i return only ```<View />``` with red background and ```flex : 1``` in ```app.js```, the black bars still exist, it's more like the app is being resized due to the ratio of the device.

Comment: Try giving `height : Dimensions.get('screen').height` and `width : Dimensions.get('screen').width`

Comment: Still the same. Not only the app content is being resized, but also the splash screen.

Comment: That's weird :(

Comment: Finally i found the root cause, i added ```<item><bitmap android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:src="@drawable/splash" /></item>``` to splash_background.xml. ```android:gravity="fill_vertical``` causing my app resized.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<item><bitmap android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:src="@drawable/splash" /></item>` to splash_background.xml.

`android:gravity="fill_vertical"` causing my app resized